# ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE when accessing my website without https

Tags: apache, centos7, conf.d

First of all, just letting you know i have a little experience with web servers and therefore, my questions might be very novice.

I am experiencing issue with my newly created website.
I have a CentOS 7 server for another website and i would like to add a new website with a different URL to this server.

The configurations for the websites are, from what i understand, in /etc/httpd/conf.d.

I have created a new .conf file for my website:

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

    #SSLCertificateFile      /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
    #SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt

    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/******/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/******/privkey.pem
    #SSLCACertificateFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/******/chain.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/******/fullchain.pem

    ServerName      mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/myproject

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/ssl-mywebsite.com-error_log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
    LogLevel error
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/ssl-mywebsite.com-access_log combined

    <Directory /var/www/myproject>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject

    <Directory /var/www/myproject>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mywebsite.com-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mywebsite.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

For some reason, the only VirtualHost that works is the 443 one. When i am trying to reach the website without the `https://` it gives me this error:

> This webpage is not available
>
> ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Is there another configuration i am not aware of that disables the not-secured traffic?

If more details are needed let me know and i will provide them.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the old site (the one on the same server) work without `https://`?

Comment: @dusan.bajic Nope. It's giving me the same error apparently.

Comment: What is the output of `firewall-cmd --list-all`

Comment: public (default, active)
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client https ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:

Comment: Ok, go with `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http`, then `sudo firewall-cmd --reload`, then try the site again

Comment: Still getting the same error...

Comment: @dusan.bajic Any other options that might cause this issue?

Comment: yes. what is the output of `netstat -nap | grep LISTE | grep tcp | grep httpd`

Comment: tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      19079/httpd tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      19079/httpd

Comment: can you again check the output of `firewall-cmd --list-all`

Comment: It's exactly the same as the first one i commented here. Does it mean my command to add the http service didn't work?

Comment: Yes. Lets first make sure that firewall  is the issue: disable firewall with `systemctl stop firewalld` and test the site. Then start it again with `systemctl start firewalld`

Comment: Ok, it is working without the firewall! So i guess that was the problem all along. What's the next step now?

Comment: try with `sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http` and then `sudo firewall-cmd --reload`

Comment: You are welcome, I will follow up with an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Verify if the CentOS7 firewall is blocking the http traffic:

```
[root@stage2 ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: eno16777984
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client https ssh
  ports: 5000/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

If you don't see `http` in `services:`, or `80/tcp` in `ports:` then you need to add a `http` service to your zone:

```
[root@stage2 ~]# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
success
```

After that reload your firewall to get access to your new service:

```
[root@stage2 ~]# firewall-cmd --reload
success
```

And verify that `http` is opened:

```
[root@stage2 ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: eno16777984
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 5000/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Comment: You are my hero!